# How to programmatically open an app if the user has not opened it even once?

Tags: android, launching-application

Is it possible for an app to get launched from code even if user has not opened once after installing.

I have tried boot complete listener , package install/ uninstall receiver.
But even these receivers  are not working when user has not opened the app at all. I am asking to just check if some one else in the community has tried this before.

Comment: why do you want this?

Comment: I have AOSP built device and i can push apps as OTA. But user is not even opening these apps.

Comment: Sorry but this really goes against user privileges. If apps could open themselves up whenever they wanted then it would be chaos.

Comment: @SnakeyHips yeah , I know that it is not good for user experience, But i am curious if this is possible or not.

Comment: AFAIK, nope. If it could be done then every app out there would be trying to do it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The answer is: no.**

If the user has never opened your application before, it is not possible to start the application.

*On some devices though, it is possible that another second application under your control could possibly start your application, although it has never been opened before by the user.*

If you do not have a second application on the device, the answer is no.

Comment: why would a "second application" be able to do this, if all the other apps can't

Comment: What do you mean by "all other apps"? The point is, the application can't open itself, but can be opened by the user or by an intent of another app.

Comment: @TimCastelijns . suppose i have 1 app already installed and used by user. Then programmatically i can open my never opened 2nd app from my first app.   JacksOnF1re thanks for the tip.